# ElasticSearch Filter by Aggregation Result

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

I just wanted to double check if I did not miss anything. In ElasticSearch 1.4 it is not possible to run any type of server side filtering on aggregation results, correct? I have for example an average percentage aggregation (0 .. ) and I want to remove everything that is above 0.9 in the results.

With ES 2.0 reducer this seems possible or right now at the client side, but that would both requiring a very high term count (in the end all of them) to figure this out.

Is there way I missed with ES 1.4 to achieve this?

Here an example:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "contextRaw.site_city",
        "order": {
          "result": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "result": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "somePercentage"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the result that now also small buckets are on top with a percentage of 1.0, while I am not interested in those, but in the ones below 0.9.

```
   "aggregations": {
      "group": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 5924518,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "value A",
               "doc_count": 3921,
               "result": {
                  "value": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "value B",
               "doc_count": 312,
               "result": {
                  "value": 1
               }
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure about the best place to ask, it got answered in the [official forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-filter-by-aggregation-result/25847).

> in 1.4 there is nothing to filter the buckets returned by the
>   aggregations on the client side. Coming in 2.0 with the new pipeline
>   aggregations there is the bucket_selector aggregation which will allow
>   you to do this kind of filtering though

.